# xfx750i support for intel pentium G3240

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a XFX750i Motherboard  and want to upgrade my CPU to Intel Pentium G3240, or Intel Pentium G3580. So my question is whether my Motherboard will support either of these CPUS??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your motherboard will not support either of those processors. The XFX 750i is a Socket [LGA775](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775) motherboard ([source](http://www.xfxstorage.com/Support/Manuals/Nforce7/750i%20Manual.pdf)) but those processors use Socket [LGA1150](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1150) which is much newer.

The Pentium and Celeron brands have been reused many times since the 90's even though different generations are not compatible.

Comment: Well!!! thanks for you quick response. as the brand name started with Pentium, I thought they had revised the previous Pentuium or core2 Due technology with the better one.

Comment: Interestingly there doesn't seem to be a Pentium G3580 so I'm guessing it's a typo? Based on the naming convention it would also be much too recent though.